# Prevention of netcutter use in the College LAN

Tags: authentication

I am a student,residing in a hostel,accessing internet,using College LAN,which is protected by Cyberoam Corporate Client authentication,and the bandwidth is equally distributed to all students but a student is illegally using netcutter to deny others of internet access.The network admin is unable to catch him because he is bypassing the Cyberoam login.How can I help the network admin to track the person down,with no admin access?

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about the software that can be used in ARP spoofing? Sorry, I just did a quick search on Netcut and wanted to be certain. If not, then ignore the rest of this post.

If so, these type of issues can be resolved on a managed switch, but the net admin will need to perform the configuration. Do you have physical access to the switch? Wireshark can detect ARP issues, but you may need to be tapped into the correct location in order to see the responses. Or, start unplugging cables and wait until someone calls about the loss of network connectivity (I am joking about that point).

It may be hard as a non-admin to locate the person, but a properly configured switch can mitigate the issue and tossing Wireshark on a computer to detect duplicate IP addresses may need to be performed by the admin.